# Check Continuity of ${y=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),x\neq0 \& y=0 for x=0} at x=0$.

Tags: limits, continuity

Question. $$y=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),x\neq0$$
$$y=0,x=0$$
Check Contunity at $x=0$

Answer. In my Text book and videos states that it is continuous. But i got conflicted LHL while solving, i'll show my attemp at the question stepwise. Please look at it and thank you for your reply.

My attempt-

$$lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$LHL- Putting\ x=0-h\  \&   h\rightarrow0$

$lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left(0-h\right)^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{0-h}\right)$
$=lim_{h\rightarrow0}h^2\sin\left(-\frac{1}{h}\right)$

Now, $\sin\left(-\theta\right)=-\sin\left(\theta\right)$ ,using this

$=lim_{h\rightarrow0}-h^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$

putting value of h whic tends to zero, we will get

$=-0$, where $0$ is approximately close to actual zero

{This is the step where other people answers are different from  me, they just ignore the minus signs and write this LHL result =$0$

My RHL is same as of the other people answers.

Comment: Since $-0=0$, I don't understand your question. Besides, what does “where $0$ is approximately close to actual zero” mean?

Comment: Note that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $$\left|x^2\sin(1/x)\right|\le x^2<\epsilon$$whenever $|x|<\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Here we are using limits to evaluate. In lmits we take things approximately close to that value, like here limit h tends to zero means that h is very close to zero like 0.00000001 or 0.00000000001. so when we put value of h in LHL ( left hand Limit) shuoldnt we get -0 or -0.000000001 .